# How do we add automation step into the customization build

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization which requires certain automation steps to be configure. Is there any option to add automation step into my customization build so that I do not have to configure it manually on client system?

Comment: I would look into doing a customization plugin (which runs during customization publish) and write a process to check for and insert your entries into the correct table(s). If no one has a better idea I can see if I can put an example together at a later date.

Comment: I asked this question of Acumatica support and they told me there was no way to package an Automation step into a customization.